# What is invalid and not well formed about this URL?

Tags: custom-link

Creating a custom link to a Google Maps page with the billing address of an account marked. Simple task, no?

Anyway what I have entered is apparently not a valid URL:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q={!Account.BillingAddress}
```

I tried surrounding it with URLENCODE(), and I checked the documentation and discovered Salesforce does this automatically if you select URL as the content source. So what's up with this?

The syntax checker says it's all good, but when I go to save it says:

> Error: Enter a URL that is valid and well-formed

Comment: I'd say if this is a valid URL depends on the content of the BillingAddress field. What's the context in which you are using this snippet?

Comment: In the content section of a new custom link on the account object. I have managed to get it working using the separate fields but if Salesforce are going to add a composite field like BillingAddress they should really make it work with things.

Comment: Account.BillingAddress is in beta. See http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_account.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it on an easy Visualforce page and it failed also.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:outputText >{!Account.BillingAddress}</apex:outputText>
</apex:page>
```

It fails, because BillingAddress is not just a text field, it is a group of fields.
You can see it if you query it.

[image: Query of Account.BillingAddress]

You have to try something like this:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q={!Account.BillingCity}&{!Account.BillingStreet}&...
```

Account.BillingAddress is in beta, so don't expect too much.

---

Source: [Account Docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_account.htm)

---

Answer (score 2):

Create a formula field of type text and use something like this formula:

```
HYPERLINK("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" & BillingStreet & ",+" & BillingCity & "+" & BillingState & "+" & BillingPostalCode, "To see map click here")
```

That works for me.
It seems you can't use BillingAddress - at least not right now.

Comment: Yes that would be a great solution for that problem.